# Getting error: kendo numeric textbox is not a function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce MVC and when i am use this code in model then i am getting error in console and not working my working code.

code:

```
 [NopResourceDisplayName("AuthCode ")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public int AuthCode { get; set; }
```

Error Image:
[image]

when in above code change type int to string and comment on [AllowHtml] then my problem solved like:

```
[NopResourceDisplayName("AuthCode ")]
          //  [AllowHtml]
            public string AuthCode { get; set; }
```

but i want to type int and [AllowHtml] its required so how to solve this error pls give me idea.

thanks in advance

Ragards,
Jatin

Comment: It seems that error is related to javascript.

Comment: How can an typeof `int` be anything other than an integer value so `[AllowHtml]` (which allows you bind to a string containing characters such as `<`) make no sense.